# Access value in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm very new to vue and still learning. My problem is that I want to access the value of the item and format it with decimal places and commas.

```
for(let j in data.table.items){
   console.log(data.table.items[j])
}
```

Code above returns this value in console:
[image: console result]

Table result:
[image: Table]
I want to get and format the values in red.
I want to get the e.g. `7900` value exclude the e.g. `201803` which is the row header. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the relevant HTML you're trying to use to display the data you're iterating over? Also, what is the desired format of the value? `7,900.00`?

Comment: @miqid Updated my question. You're correct with my desired format. Thanks.

Comment: You could define a filter which provides your desired format. Here's a crude example the piggybacks off the `toLocaleString()` method—http://plnkr.co/edit/dsDEW6?p=preview

Comment: `<li v-for="item in table.items">{{ item[201803] | format }}</li>` can I insert this one directly in a Vue file?

Comment: I don't know how you're rendering your table (you've included a screenshot, but not the markup) but, yes, you can put HTML in `*.vue` files—they must be inside `<template>` tags.

Comment: @miqid Can you please add your answer here, so that I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my suggestion in a comment as an answer as it appears to have helped.

The official documentation describes a few ways you can use to define filters to format values rendered to a page - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

To get your numeric values formatted such that they are delimited with commas and show a decimal component, you can take advantage of the [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) call in JS.

[Here's an example of it in action.](https://plnkr.co/edit/dsDEW6?p=preview)